# Read stdin with fgets, fill each line in an array and print each line

Tags: c, while-loop, malloc, stdin, fgets

I want to read the `stdin` with `fgets`.

Then, I want to read each line. My lines are strings separated with `' '`.
For example, this could be a line: `1 2 ab`

I thought than I should use a `malloc` to count the number of params in my line because this number can vary from a line to another.
`1 2 3 4` has 4 but `a b 2` has 3.

I cut the line with `strtok` and then I fill my `malloc` with the **tokens** and I print them.

The final result is only to print each lines.

For example, this is a **file.txt**:

```
1 2 33 4
a b1 c
4 b l 11
```

And I do:

```
$ cat file.txt | ./a.out
```

It should print:

```
1 2 33 4
a b1 c
4 b l 11
```

but it doesn't!

Can you guys help me with this please :O

Furthermore, I want to use array to count the tokens and to work with them later. For example, I need to work separately with all the second param of each line, so array[1].

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv) {
 
    while (fgets(argv, sizeof(argv), stdin) != NULL) {
        char *array = (char *)malloc(sizeof(argv));
        char *token = strtok(argv, " ");
        strtok(token, "\n");
        int i = 0;

        while (token != NULL) {
            array[i] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            printf("%d\n", array[i]);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To begin with, why are you using `argv` as the destination buffer for `fgets`? And is this the reason you declare it *wrong*?

Comment: Furthermore, the size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself, not whatever it might point to. There seems to be some really basic misunderstandings in your teaching material, or how you understand it. Or you just guess around and hope for the best?

Comment: As for what you want to do, you can do it with only six lines (no empty lines and trailing opening curly brace  like you do). There are also *many* examples all over the Internet on how to do it.

Comment: Why do you care about counting tokens if you are just going to output the line read from input? Just `fgets()` and `fputs()`?? If you really need to hold each input in an array of unknown length, then allocating is proper, but you need to allocate both pointers and then storage.  Also `cat file.txt | ./a.out` is a classic *UUOc* (Unnecessary Use Of `cat`), that's what redirection is for, e.g. `./a.out < file.txt`. Let us know on whether you really need to tokenize each line.

Comment: I want to count them to use them later. For example, to list the second token of each line. So array[1] for each line

Comment: Oh and if your compiler doesn't already scream at you for doing bad things, you should enable verbose and more warnings, and treat them as errors that must be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is count the tokens and output them, then you can simply use a pointer to the token and do not need to allocate storage. Using `strtok()` would be a good way to go. (note: if you have empty fields, you will need to parse using another method as `strtok()` will consider sequential delimiters as a single delimiter). The string passed to `strtok()` must be mutable as `strtok()` modifies the string (make a copy if you need to preserve the original)

Your approach is to read each line with `fgets()` into a sufficiently sized buffer (character array), zero your counter and then tokenize the line, incrementing the count for each token and output the token separated by a space.

You could do that as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char line[MAXC];    /* storage for line */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp)) {
        size_t  toks = 0,
                len;
        line[(len = strcspn (line, "\n"))] = 0;     /* trim \n, save length */
        for (char *p = strtok (line, " \t"); p; p = strtok (NULL, " \t"))
            printf (toks++ ? " %s" : "%s", p);
        printf ("%*s\t(%zu tokens)\n", (int)len % 8, " ", toks);
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

Above a *ternary* is used to control the output of the space-separator (nothing before the first token -- when the count is zero, and then a single space before each subsequent token). The count of the tokens is appended to the end of each line.

(the `strlen()` of each line is just used to tidy up the spacing between the end of each output line and the appended count by adding the fractional part of a tab, if needed)

**Example Use/Output**

With your example data in the file `dat/tokfile.txt`, you would receive:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_tok_count dat/tokfile.txt
1 2 33 4        (4 tokens)
a b1 c          (3 tokens)
4 b l 11        (4 tokens)
```

By taking the filename as the first argument to the program, or reading from `stdin` by default if no argument is given, you can redirect information to your program as well, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/fgets_tok_count < dat/tokfile.txt
```

Or heaven forbid your UUOc form will also work:

```
$ cat dat/tokfile.txt | ./bin/fgets_tok_count
```

**Dynamically Storing Unknown Number of Tokens Per-Line**

To dynamically stored each token and preserve each for the duration of your tokenization loop, then all you need is a pointer-to-pointer-to `char` and a counter to track the number of pointers and strings allocated. You can do that similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char line[MAXC];            /* storage for line */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fgets (line, MAXC, fp)) {
        char **tokens = NULL;
        size_t  len = 0,
                toks = 0;
        line[(len = strcspn (line, "\n"))] = 0;     /* trim \n, save length */
        /* loop over each token */
        for (char *p = strtok (line, " \t"); p; p = strtok (NULL, " \t")) {
            size_t toklen = strlen (p);
            /* allocate/validate 1 additional pointer for tokens */
            void *tmp = realloc (tokens, (toks + 1) * sizeof *tokens);
            if (!tmp) {
                perror ("realloc-tokens");
                break;
            }
            tokens = tmp;
            /* allocate/validate storage for token of len + 1 */
            if (!(tokens[toks] = malloc (toklen + 1))) {
                perror ("malloc-tokens[toks]");
                break;
            }
            /* copy token to allocated block */
            memcpy (tokens[toks], p, toklen + 1);
            toks++;     /* increment no. of tokens in line */
        }
        /* output all stored line tokens and no. of tokens */
        for (size_t i = 0; i < toks; i++) {
            printf (i ? " %s" : "%s", tokens[i]);
            free (tokens[i]);   /* done with stored token, free token */
        }
        free (tokens);          /* free pointers */
        
        printf ("%*s\t(%zu tokens)\n", (int)len % 8, " ", toks);
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

(the program output is the same)

Basically, above, `realloc` is used to allocate storage for 1-additional pointer each time a token is found, `malloc` is then used to allocate for the length of the token (+1), and then the token is copied to that allocated block. When you are done tokenizing the line, the `tokens` pointer points to a block of memory containing `toks` pointers, to which a block of memory holding each token was assigned in turn. After all tokenization and storage is complete, the same output is produced by looping over the pointers, outputting the tokens (and the number of tokens). All memory is then freed.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I would need the storage because I want to use some strings in each line though!

Comment: Okay, that's not hard to add. Do you need permanent storage for all tokens in all lines or just saving the token during the scope of the read-loop? (If you just need it during the scope of the read-loop, you can just allocate pointers, if you need storage for all times, you need to allocate a pointer for each line, a pointer for each token and `strlen(token) + 1` storage for each token) What are you hoping to accomplish? To save all tokens in all lines separately, you will need to become a **Three Star Programmer** (which generally means you need to rethink what you are trying to do...)

Comment: `len = strlen(line) - 1;` fails to index the `'\n'` when it does not exist and leads to UB when the first character read is a _null character_.  `len = strcspn(line, "\n");` is a good alternative.

Comment: Yes, we should use `strcspn()`, but I was avoiding the additional layer and relying on POSIX end of file. Will note. (updated)

Comment: I only need them during the loop! When the loop ends I don't need anything!

Comment: If you only need them in a loop, you can just use a `char**` and allocated a pointer for each and then storage for the token. I'll cut down the example I had done that stores all tokens for all lines and post the version preserving the tokens in the read-loop in a few minutes.

Comment: Hey I have some quesitons:
•Why do we need to define MAXC? It is not enogh to say that the maximum is the size of argv?
•What means fopen(argv[1],"r")? What's the "r"?
•Why do you strok " \t"? I don't use tabs but spaces

It works very very well!! I thank you a lot!
But can I know why my version doesn't work that well? I guess I have errors, can you try to help me with it please :D

Comment: We define `MAXC` (max no. of characters per line) in order to use (and re-use) `line` to read lines of data from the input file. Unless you are on a microcontroller, a 1K buffer (or more) is fine for a line buffer. The `FILE *fp` line uses a *ternary* to either open the file with the filename given, or assign `stdin` to `fp` by default if no filename is given. (it is a shorthand `if...else...` statement in the form of `test ? if_true : if_false` and can be used virtually anywhere). Generally, I don't use tabs either, but here that was the simplest way to line up the no. of tokens output `:)`